# CPU Usage in WMI Query showing incorrect value >100%

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, wmi-query

I am trying to find the CPU usage of my WPF application using the WMI query and I seem to be getting incorrect values.

My application that is queried via WMI using the process name return's CPU% greater than 100.

```
string processQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process Where Name like \"" + processName + "%\"";
_processSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(searchScope, processQuery);

var processTimes = _processSearcher.Get()
                              .Cast<ManagementObject>()
                              .Select(mo => new ProcessCounter()
                              {
                                  Name = (string)mo["Name"],
                                  ProcessID = (uint)mo["IDProcess"],
                                  Usage = (ulong)mo["PercentProcessorTime"],
                                  ThreadCount = (uint)mo["ThreadCount"],
                                  PrivateBytes = (ulong)mo["PrivateBytes"],
                              }
                              )
                              .ToArray();

foreach (ProcessCounter mgtObj in processTimes)
{
    double dblUsage;
    if (Double.TryParse(mgtObj.Usage.ToString(), out dblUsage))
    {
       double percentCPU = Math.Round(dblUsage / coreCount);
       totalCPU += percentCPU;
    }
}
```

coreCount here is Environment.ProcessorCount.

The value of the total CPU is around 300-400.

Any pointers here, if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: This might not actually be a problem. This can happen if the number of virtual CPU cores on your system is higher than the number of physical CPU cores.  I don't understand why though, it's something to do with how time slices are calculated.  Google "site:stackoverflow.com cpu usage over 100%"

Comment: Why you are using WMI when you have the [PerformanceCounter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)  class. anyway I suggest you check the cpu usage with that class and check if the answer is the same